# Aggregate time series in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a variable onto time slots, but I am not sure how to do this in a Pythonic way. My plan is to aggregate it every ten seconds. 
My time data is the first column and it is stated in seconds from midnight. The second column is the variable I want to aggregate. Most of the entries are zero, but the others are actual numbers that I want to sum.

So the idea is to sum column two for every ten seconds elapsed from column 1.
The matrix vector would have the time every ten seconds for the first column and the aggregated variable for the second column.

My first idea was to do a while loop on column two and summing all the numbers while we are inside the same time slot. And place it inside a for loop for each 10 second increment. This seems incredibly heavy and slow.

Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thank you.

Sample data:

```
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009535350000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009723610000219e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420009926809999888e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420019142339999962e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420025728430000163e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420030975760000001e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420031578240000090e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420033592689999932e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420046674769999663e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420046679600000061e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420074155890000111e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420074291200000152e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420076289620000171e+04    -3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420076459099999920e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420080930030000309e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420088430179999705e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420089157010000054e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.420103050939999957e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420118753419999848e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420118888490000245e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420141332990000228e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420191020060000301e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420282872450000286e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.420304732930000318e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420305702279999969e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420308584690000134e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420310770000000048e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420319724010000209e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420338125820000278e+04    -6.000000000000000000e+00
3.420341430170000240e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420341743809999753e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420365752020000218e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420377651160000096e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420377900809999846e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420394856640000216e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420477753839999787e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420477777210000204e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420509855940000125e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420509857180000108e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420509858389999863e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420509858600000007e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420510251910000079e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420540111949999846e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420560046090000105e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420650914059999923e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420677362859999994e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420677385650000360e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420680100729999685e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420680135709999740e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420740102699999989e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420760059799999726e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420827570510000078e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420827846660000068e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420860100809999858e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420860318459999689e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420860717129999830e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.420920105229999899e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420949705469999753e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420949705469999753e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420949874789999740e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420949964329999784e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950525599999673e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950532879999810e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950537430000259e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950638910000271e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950643239999772e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420950668009999936e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420950796770000306e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420951590530000249e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951602249999996e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951673219999793e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951805140000215e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951861829999689e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951993930000026e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.420951995310000348e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420952149579999968e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420953443149999657e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420955497840000317e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.420980103039999813e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420980107300000236e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420980108509999991e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420989885620000132e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420989886560000014e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.420989887540000200e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421022118190000037e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421028878499999701e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421029493570000341e+04    -6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421030143400000088e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421040105849999964e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421048329460000241e+04    -6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421048642470000050e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421085856629999762e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421091312309999921e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421091378969999641e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421091715290000138e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421118993179999961e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421119293469999684e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421120108150000306e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421125067030000355e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421125067030000355e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421125072869999713e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421125074440000026e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421125075079999806e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421125081070000306e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421125213139999687e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421125223679999908e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421128031339999870e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421128036189999693e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421129058039999654e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421136299729999882e+04    -6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421136675249999826e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421144104959999822e+04    -6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421144451439999830e+04    6.000000000000000000e+00
3.421180177070000354e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421180182290000084e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421180183370000304e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421180184079999890e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421180240860000049e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421182461470000271e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421182466330000170e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421183488509999734e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421209945889999653e+04    7.500000000000000000e+01
3.421213015650000307e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250285479999729e+04    2.500000000000000000e+01
3.421250285479999729e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250292720000289e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250293499999680e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250294089999807e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421250461730000097e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250660069999867e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250661260000197e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421250662810000358e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250862849999976e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421250865109999722e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251071360000060e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251073390000238e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251200200000312e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251202500000363e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251290870000230e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421251292259999900e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421251417010000296e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421252315950000047e+04    -3.750000000000000000e+02
3.421253324080000311e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421253324419999990e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421253325169999880e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421280107870000211e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421280108050000126e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421280109909999737e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421300649369999883e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.421300649369999883e+04    -5.000000000000000000e+00
3.421301662930000020e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421301664270000038e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421308269650000148e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+00
3.421308569990000251e+04    1.000000000000000000e+00
3.421340113990000100e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421360080849999940e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421360081950000313e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421429604950000066e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421429604950000066e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421465075329999672e+04    1.750000000000000000e+02
3.421465535619999719e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421480113819999679e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421500744149999809e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421500745640000241e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421501012210000044e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421501918660000229e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421506023750000168e+04    2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421506026279999787e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421506290029999946e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421529837140000018e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.421540116690000286e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421549945029999799e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421554515879999963e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421556687119999697e+04    -3.000000000000000000e+02
3.421556832669999858e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421560137959999702e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421591907280000305e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421640112349999981e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421660092140000052e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421780116010000347e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.421860098989999824e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.422180125080000289e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.422181661359999998e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.422946705189999921e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.422947095989999798e+04    3.000000000000000000e+02
3.422947237350000069e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.422980151579999801e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423008524700000271e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423035811159999867e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423036595089999901e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423315292909999698e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+00
3.423315298620000249e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.423315299590000359e+04    -1.000000000000000000e+02
3.423315301110000291e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423315437930000189e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423315469930000108e+04    -2.000000000000000000e+02
3.423315568000000349e+04    0.000000000000000000e+00
3.423317673620000278e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
3.423318700569999783e+04    1.000000000000000000e+02
```

Comment: You *may* want to consider using `pandas`, which comes with a *ton* of time-series functionality built-in. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: ok, I have found a way to transform numpy into pandas: pd.DataFrame(). Should I transform the time data to TimeStamp in order to count the seconds?

Comment: Yep. The I would use `df.set_index('my_time_column', inplace=True)`. Then you can do something like: `df.groupby(df.index.seconds).sum()`

Comment: can you explain how did you get such a timestamp? It doesnt look like a standard UNIX epoch (# of (nano-), (micro-), (mili-), seconds)

Comment: @MaxU that is seconds from midnight.

Comment: @python_newbie, from the current midnight?

Comment: yes, I am using only one day.

Comment: it comes from a code that reads binary file. These are the lines that read the time:   timestamp = float(unpack('>i', message[1:5])[0])
            time = seconds + (timestamp/1000000000.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I got a weird error when running that code: 
  File "<ipython-input-27-b6246b19d985>", line 1, in <module>
    a.groupby(a.index.seconds).sum()

AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Comment: So, a.set_index('time', inplace=True)   puts the time column in place of the index column I had before. But then it does not have a seconds attribute because it is still a number, right?

Comment: @python_newbie yeah, so, actually, it should have been `a.index.second` without the "s", but that will only work with a `DatetimeIndex`. If you just have floating-point values though, try using `a.groupby(df['a'] // 10).sum()` Note, `//` is just integer-division, so `123.456 // 10 == 12.0`, so basically, all times within the same 10-second slot will be grouped together. EDIT I see MaxU already beat me to the point...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for explaining. I actually did not know that //10 would be integer division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['ts','val'])

In [31]: df.groupby(df['ts']//10*10)['val'].sum()
Out[31]:
ts
34200.0    1806.0
34210.0     907.0
34220.0     100.0
34230.0    -201.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Source DF:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
               ts    val
0    34200.095354    0.0
1    34200.095354    0.0
2    34200.095354    0.0
3    34200.095354    0.0
4    34200.095354    0.0
5    34200.095354    0.0
6    34200.095354    0.0
7    34200.095354    0.0
8    34200.095354    0.0
9    34200.095354    0.0
..            ...    ...
237  34230.365951    0.0
238  34233.152929   -1.0
239  34233.152986 -100.0
240  34233.152996 -100.0
241  34233.153011    0.0
242  34233.154379    0.0
243  34233.154699 -200.0
244  34233.155680    0.0
245  34233.176736  100.0
246  34233.187006  100.0

[247 rows x 2 columns]
```

`df['ts']//10*10` - will round timestamps up to 10 seconds, so we can use it for groupping later on:

```
In [34]: df['ts']//10*10
Out[34]:
0      34200.0
1      34200.0
2      34200.0
3      34200.0
4      34200.0
5      34200.0
6      34200.0
7      34200.0
8      34200.0
9      34200.0
        ...
237    34230.0
238    34230.0
239    34230.0
240    34230.0
241    34230.0
242    34230.0
243    34230.0
244    34230.0
245    34230.0
246    34230.0
Name: ts, Length: 247, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @python_newbie, i've added a short explanation into an answer - please check

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!